# Publish Blazor project with library project reference to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, blazor

## Project reference

The project `BankCapitalWasm` has a project reference `Bank`:

[image]

This shows up in the reference manager as follows:

[image]

## Build

I can build and run `BankCapitalWasm` just fine locally.

## Publish to Azure

When I publish to Azure, I get the following:

[image]

The Error List shows this:

[image]

The Output window contains:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Bank, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Bank -> C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\Bank\bin\Release\net6.0\Bank.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: BankCapitalWasm, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>BankCapitalWasm -> C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\bin\Release\net6.0\BankCapitalWasm.dll
2>BankCapitalWasm (Blazor output) -> C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\bin\Release\net6.0\wwwroot
3>------ Publish started: Project: BankCapitalWasm, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,IL2026,IL2041,IL2042,IL2043,IL2056,IL2045,IL2046,IL2050,IL2032,IL2055,IL2057,IL2058,IL2059,IL2060,IL2061,IL2096,IL2062,IL2063,IL2064,IL2065,IL2066,IL2067,IL2068,IL2069,IL2070,IL2071,IL2072,IL2073,IL2074,IL2075,IL2076,IL2077,IL2078,IL2079,IL2080,IL2081,IL2082,IL2083,IL2084,IL2085,IL2086,IL2087,IL2088,IL2089,IL2090,IL2091,IL2092,IL2093,IL2094,IL2095,IL2097,IL2098,IL2099,IL2106,IL2103,IL2107,IL2109,IL2110,IL2111,IL2114,IL2115,IL2112,IL2113,1701,1702,2008 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /warn:6 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NET;NET6_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /nullable:enable /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.metadata\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.json\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.abstractions\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.physical\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.filesystemglobbing\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\6.0.1\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\6.0.0\lib\netstandard2.1\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\6.0.0\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop.webassembly\6.0.6\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\netstandard.dll" /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\radzen.blazor\3.19.10\lib\net5.0\Radzen.Blazor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Buffers.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Formats.Asn1.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\system.io.pipelines\6.0.3\lib\net6.0\System.IO.Pipelines.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\system.linq.dynamic.core\1.2.12\lib\net5.0\System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Memory.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Http.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Reader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Resources.Writer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Loader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ServiceProcess.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Channels.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Transactions.Local.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.ValueTuple.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\ref\net6.0\WindowsBase.dll" /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\net6.0\BankCapitalWasm.dll /refout:obj\Release\net6.0\refint\BankCapitalWasm.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:10.0 /analyzerconfig:obj\Release\net6.0\BankCapitalWasm.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzerconfig:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\analyzers\build\config\analysislevel_6_default.editorconfig" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\ILLink.CodeFixProvider.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\analyzers\ILLink.RoslynAnalyzer.dll" /analyzer:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.analyzers\6.0.6\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Analyzers.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\dharm\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\6.0.1\analyzers\dotnet\roslyn4.0\cs\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Generators.dll /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\6.0.6\analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\..\\source-generators\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.SourceGenerator.Tooling.Internal.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\targets\..\\source-generators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.dll" /additionalfile:App.razor /additionalfile:Pages\BankingSystem.razor /additionalfile:Pages\Counter.razor /additionalfile:Pages\FetchData.razor /additionalfile:Pages\Index.razor /additionalfile:Shared\SurveyPrompt.razor /additionalfile:_Imports.razor /additionalfile:Shared\MainLayout.razor /additionalfile:Shared\NavMenu.razor Client\Program.cs obj\Release\net6.0\BankCapitalWasm.GlobalUsings.g.cs "obj\Release\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\net6.0\BankCapitalWasm.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\BankingSystem.razor(3,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bank' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\Index.razor(11,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bank' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\Index.razor(14,13): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bank' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\BankingSystem.razor(29,22): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Economy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\BankingSystem.razor(29,33): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Economy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\BankingSystem.razor(6,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Economy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\RadzenSlider\BankCapitalWasm\Pages\BankingSystem.razor(8,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Economy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

3>Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

## Workaround 1: Copy Local

If I set the `Copy Local` property on the `Bank` project reference to `Yes` as shown:

[image]

the publish step appears to run into the same issue.

## Workaround 2: Embed Interop Types

If I set the `Embed Interop Types` property on the `Bank` project reference to `Yes` as shown:

[image]

then simply building the project locally runs into errors:

[image]

## Question

What's the recommended approach to publishing a project to Azure which has a project reference?

## Code

If it would help to view the code, here are the projects mentioned above:

https://github.com/dharmatech/FractionalReserveBankingTest/tree/master/BankCapitalWasm
https://github.com/dharmatech/FractionalReserveBankingTest/tree/master/Bank

Don't worry, this is not for a real bank.  It's just a small demo of fractional reserve banking in Blazor.

## Update

I used the `New` button to create a new publish profile:

[image]

After going through the steps to create a new profile and publishing to it, the project appears to work!

I had been using the original profile with other projects in this solution so perhaps there's some setting in there that caused the issue.

Anyway, if you run into the issue, consider creating a new profile.

Answer (score 2):

- I have downloaded the same Solution which you have provided in the ***github*** and able to add the class library project reference

[image]

- Right click on the ***BankCapitalWasm*** Application and click on ***Set as Startup Project*** , then try to publish

[image]

- Able to build locally and Published  successfully to Azure  and able to access the Application without any issues

[image]

***Output of the published Application***
[image]

***.csproj file of BlazorCapitalWasm***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.6" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Radzen.Blazor" Version="3.19.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Bank\Bank.csproj">
      <EmbedInteropTypes></EmbedInteropTypes>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Referenced dll files from Bank Class Library in ***KUDU***

[image]

Comment: That's interesting... So you didn't have to change anything in the code to get it to publish to Azure?

Comment: OK... So I created a new publish profile and that seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Yes,I was able to publish with your given code itself. Added Bank class library reference ,build locally, and done new publish.